# Trying to save image from numpy array with PIL, getting errors

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

trying to save an inverted image, saved inverted RGB colour data in array pixelArray, then converted this to a numpy array. Not sure what is wrong but any help is appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('image.jpg')
pixels = img.load()
width, height = img.size

pixelArray = []

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        r, g, b = pixels[x, y]
        pixelArray.append((255-r,255-b,255-g))

invertedImageArray = np.array(pixelArray, dtype=np.uint8)

invertedImage = Image.fromarray(invertedImageArray, 'RGB')
invertedImage.save('inverted-image.jpeg')
img.show()
```

getting error code "ValueError : not enough image data"

Comment: No need for lists or `for` loops, just use Numpy `im = 255-im`

Answer (score 1):

Your np.array creates an array shape (4000000, 3) instead of (2000, 2000, 3).

Also, you may find that directly mapping the subtraction to the NumPy array is faster and easier

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('image.jpg')

pixelArray = np.array(img)
pixelArray = 255 - pixelArray

invertedImageArray = np.array(pixelArray, dtype=np.uint8)

invertedImage = Image.fromarray(invertedImageArray, 'RGB')
invertedImage.save('inverted-image.jpeg')
```

Comment: thank you VicLobato, I am now able to reprogram the whole internet with my eyes closed thanks to your help

Answer (score 0):

PIL already provides an easier way to invert the image colours with the `ImageOps` module.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

img = Image.open('image.jpg')

invertedImage = ImageOps.invert(img)
invertedImage.save('inverted-image.jpeg')
```